# Struts2 Form submission with asynchronous jQuery ajax not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, struts2

I am trying to make a simple asynchronous Struts2 form submission using jQuery ajax feature. However, whatever i try, the jquery is not getting triggered.

Normal form submission is working smoothly but i need an asynchronous call which can fetch result from server without reloading page.

I have already tried normal forms, submission with JSON plugin and everything else that i could get my hands on from youtube, internet, stackoverflow etc. Please help, I am really unable to understand what i am doing wrong.

Using jQuery 1.3.2, Struts2: 2.3.14

[Link to Eclipse Project](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6ZVy8oMfUzXT2tvUjlNamdkUGs/view?usp=sharing)

P.S : I am using jQuery, AJAX call with Struts2 for first Time.

```js
   $(document).ready(function() {
    
    $("#updtTslcDL").mousedown(function(){
     
     $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',  
      data: {
       tslcText : $('#txtTslcDL').val(),
       userid : <% session.getAttribute("userid").toString(); %>,
       username : 'c'       
      },
      dataType:'json',
      url: 'updateTSLC.wht',
      success:function(response){       
       $('#msgTslcDL').html(response.out);
      },
            error: function(msg) {
                if (msg.statusText != "OK") {
                    alert("Alert", "Error occured while retriving data.");
                }
            }
           //Finish $.ajax()
     });
     event.preventDefault();
    //Finish $('#updtTslcDL').click()
    });
   //Finish $(document).ready()
   });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
 
  <div>
       
   <s:form id="frmUpdtTslcDL_s" theme="simple">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
      <s:textarea id="txtTslcDL" name="tslcText" rows="1" cols="7" value="2222:45"/>     
    <%-- <s:hidden id="userid" name="userid" value="%{#session.userid}"/>
    <s:hidden id="username" name="username" value="%{#session.username}"/>  --%> 
    <s:submit id="updtTslcDL" name = "updtTslcDL" cssClass="button" value="Update" onclick="return false;"/>     
   </s:form>
   <!-- <%-- 
   <form id="frmUpdtTslcDL" action="updateTSLC.wht" method="post">
    <div>
     <textarea id="txtTslcDL" name="tslcText" rows="1" cols="7">123</textarea>
     <input type="hidden" id="iptuserid" name="userid" value=<% session.getAttribute("userid").toString(); %> />
     <input type="hidden" id="iptusername" name="username" value=<% session.getAttribute("username").toString(); %> />
     <input type="submit" id="iptupdtTslcDL" name = "updtTslcDL" class="button" value="Update"/>
    </div>
   </form>
    --%> -->
   <div id="msgTslcDL"/>
  </div>
 </body>
```

Struts.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
<struts>
    <constant name="struts.action.extension" value="wht" />
    <package name="default" namespace="/" extends="struts-default, json-default">
        <action name="validateAuthorization" class="test.ValidateUserAction" method="validateUser">
            <result name="success" type="redirect">/test.jsp</result>
            <result name="error" type="redirect">/error.jsp</result>
        </action>

        <action name="updateTSLC" class="test.TestAction" method="updateTSLC">
            <result name="success" type="json">
                <param name="root">jsonResponse</param>
                <param name="location">/test.jsp</param>
            </result>
            <result name="error">/error.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

Action Class:

```
package test;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletRequestAware;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class TestAction extends ActionSupport implements ServletRequestAware {

    private HttpServletRequest request = null;

    private String tslcText;
    private String userid;
    private String username;

    private Map<String, String> jsonResponse=new HashMap<String, String>();

    public String updateTSLC(){

        System.out.println(getTslcText()+getUserid()+getUsername());
        jsonResponse.put("out", "test: "+getTslcText()+", userid: "+getUserid()+", username: "+getUsername()+"_response");

        return SUCCESS;
    }

    public String getTslcText() {
        return tslcText;
    }

    public void setTslcText(String tslcText) {
        this.tslcText = tslcText;
    }

    public String getUserid() {
        return userid;
    }

    public void setUserid(String userid) {
        this.userid = userid;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public Map<String, String> getJsonResponse() {
        return jsonResponse;
    }

    public void setJsonResponse(Map<String, String> jsonResponse) {
        this.jsonResponse = jsonResponse;
    }

    @Override
    public void setServletRequest(HttpServletRequest inRequest) {
        request = inRequest;
    }

}
```

Comment: Is your Action layer getting called. And what error do you get ?

Comment: Yes My action layer is indeed getting called. I am printing data sent from test.jsp into action method. There is no error with the server end processing at all. It's just that when i click **Update** button, the jquery click event does not launch.

Comment: Move your onmousedown code into a function and on ajax success rebind the code to your button id.

Comment: Waqar...Thanks a lot for your time to help me, however, as it seems the code is working now. I just made a few changes, really to say reverted back to some previous things i tried already. Miraculously it's working.

Comment: (1) Why `mousedown` and not `click`? (2) What does a "userid" look like, is it numeric? I.e., check your JS console.

Comment: Well, actually i was thinking for submitting the form at the instant when mouse button is pressed but not yet released. But really, i understand that it was not required. Thanks for your commenting on that though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Finally***, it's working on making few further changes, although i tried doing these yesterday already. Not sure what extra i put there but OMG it's working now.

1. Uncommented the **userid** hidden field.
2. Replaced scriptlet `<% session.getAttribute("userid").toString(); %>` in ajax call with `$('#userid').val()`. [ Using scriptlet was causing the page to redirect for some reason].
3. Replaced `$("#updtTslcDL").mousedown(` with `$('#frmUpdtTslcDL').submit(`.

Comment: the hidden field is not required if you use it as a parameter.